# On solaris, when compiled with g++, socket() and bind() are not getting intercepted using dlsym()

Tags: sockets, gcc, g++, solaris, xnet

I have written a simple server program using socket functions.
When compiled with `g++`, it gives undefined symbol error for send, __xnet_socket, listen, accept, __xnet_bind.

Why the symbols for socket and bind are different than others. 
Also, when the program is compiled using `gcc`, this '`xnet`' difference does not happen.
This linking error goes when linked with `libsocket.so`.

Actually, I am writing a shared library which overloads these socket API's and intercept them using `dlsym()`.
On Solaris, when this library is compiled with gcc, these calls goes through the library, but when compiled with `g++`, `socket()` and `bind()` calls does not gets intercepted, but all other apis goes through the library.

Has `libxnet.so` to do something with this?
Can dtrace be of some help?

Comment: *When compiled with g++, it gives undefined symbol error for send, __xnet_socket, listen, accept, __xnet_bind.* That sounds like you're not linking with `-lxnet`.  Post your link command[s].

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with libsocket (via `-lsocket`) in order for the linker to pick up those functions. libxnet is a filter library in 11.3; the functions were moved from libxnet to libsocket, libnsl and libc.

I've found in the past when building OSS on Solaris that appending `-lsocket -lnsl` to LDLIBS generally gets me through configure and build stages with ease. The linker is smart enough to remove unnecessary references from the output.